# Algorithm for possible permutations based on percentages

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation

Im looking to find all the possible permutations of the following 6 letters in 7 letter sets. `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`.

The problem is that each letter corresponds to a certain percentage. The total percentage for each 7 letter set needs to be 100%

A: `0% <= a < 1%`

B: `1% <= b <= 5%`
C: `5% < c <= 25%`
D: `25% < d <= 50%`
E: `50% < e <= 75%`
F: `75% < f <= 100%`

For example, these are possible sets:

- `[a,a,a,a,a,a,f]` : all the A's could be 0% and the F could be 100%
- `[d,d,b,a,a,a,a]` : D's could be 47% each. B could be 5% and the A's could make up the remaining 1%.

But these are impossible: `[f,a,a,a,a,a,f]` or `[e,e,e,a,a,a,a]` because their totals are more than 100%.

Ive been trying to do it in javascript but haven't had much luck. I was able to generate all the possible permutations using this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v4s6xk5x/. Unfortunately, this doesn't take into account the percentages.

I really just want the permutations and don't need code. But code in any language would be helpful so that I can understand what is going on.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Just annotate each selection (notice they're (multi-)subsets, not permutations) during the generation with the min and max sum of percentages they already have, then filter out those whose interval doesn't include 100.

Comment: Sounds a lot like https://www.reference.com/business-finance/many-ways-can-make-change-dollar-1dcacf4984548e6d?qo=contentSimilarQuestions

Comment: True @Will , it's similar to that one only but the problem is one char represents a range of percentage and not a constant specific value, I am working on a brute force approach right now...

Comment: Recursion seems the obvious way to go. Pick any letter which keeps the minimum total <= 100% and recurse, then after the last step save if the maximum total >=100%.

Comment: When you say (for example) 26%, do you really mean "more than 25%"? Or is the gap between 25 and 26% really unusable?

Comment: @Bergi, im not too sure what you're saying I should do there

Comment: @m69 I tried some recursion but i just kept getting jumbled up. You think you could get me started with the terminal case for your idea?

Comment: @rici I guess I mean greater than 25%. Ill fix that now.

Comment: @Orcinuss Uh, after having looked at your jsfiddle I would recommend to start with understanding/(re)writing the combinatorics algorithm yourself instead of using a library. Once you did that, you'll probably get my comment as well.

Comment: If one letter appears more than once is a combination, could each of its appearances represent a different percentages? (Like [a,a,a,b], where each `a` is a different percentage.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן  yes. So B could be and value between 1 and 5. It could also be 1.5 but that starts getting complicated.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: It makes no difference. Suppose you had three `a`'s with different percentages; if you replaced all three percentages with the average, you would have exactly the same sum and the average of in-range percentages is guaranteed to be within the range, since that range is contiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of a recursive solution:

As input you have:

```
size: 7
letters: [a,b,c,d,e,f]
minval: [0,1,5,25,50,75]
maxval: [1,5,25,50,75,100]
```

Start by making an empty set and a minimum and maximum value of this set:

```
set: []
min: 0
max: 0
```

Then pass this set to the recursive function, which should:

- Iterate over every letter.
- Check whether the set's min value + the letter's min value <= 100.
- If it is, create a copy of the set, min and max with the letter and the letter's min and max value added; otherwise, continue with next letter.
- If the length of the set copy equals size, and its max value >= 100, this is a valid set; print or add to output.
- if the length of the set copy is smaller than size, recurse with set_copy, min_copy and max_copy.

This should work for any size, any number of letters, and any set of min and max values, whether they are ordered or not.

This will produce duplicates, like:

```
[a,a,a,a,a,a,f]
[a,a,a,a,a,f,a]
[a,a,a,a,f,a,a]
...
```

If you  only want to generate unique solutions, start iterating over the letters from the previous letter that was added to the set.

---

Here's a code example. It's a literal translation of the steps laid out above, with the added feature that it only generates unique solutions by passing the index of the previously added letter to the recursion (variable `prev`) and then starts iterating from that letter to the last. If you want non-unique solutions, start iterating from 0 each time.

Checking whether the minimum values are `< 100` instead of `<= 100` makes sure that all ranges exclude the low threshold and include the high threshold.

Note that all variables received as arguments by `addLetter()` or declared with `var` inside `addLetter()` are local variables, and seperate for each recursion.

```js
function rangeSet(size, letters, minval, maxval) {
    addLetter([], 0, 0, 0);

    function addLetter(set, min, max, prev) {
        for (var lt = prev; lt < letters.length; lt++) {
            if (min + minval[lt] < 100) {
                var set_copy = set.concat([letters[lt]]);
                var min_copy = min + minval[lt];
                var max_copy = max + maxval[lt];
                if (set_copy.length == size) {
                    if (max_copy >= 100) {
                        document.write(set_copy + "<br>");
                    }
                }
                else addLetter(set_copy, min_copy, max_copy, lt);
            }
        }
    }
}

rangeSet(7, ['a','b','c','d','e','f'], [0,1,5,25,50,75], [1,5,25,50,75,100]);
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed you were mixing exclusive and inclusive ranges like `5 < c <= 25` but that's easily fixed.

Comment: Alright, I think I have a good start on this. I am running into an issue though with continuing onto the next letter. From my understanding, the set's min value + the letter's min value will always be 0 when iterating through a. Is this not the case? Here's my new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkkqofbf/

Comment: @Orcinuss Iterating over every letter should be done with a loop inside the recursive function, not by using a variable defined outside of it.

Comment: I think the point at which I push letters on to the set is wrong. That, or my whole function is wrong. Currently, the function will add 7 A's and then iterate. I end up with `[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,b,c,d,e,f]`. Any help would be appreciated. Heres my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkkqofbf/

Comment: @Orcinuss "lt" should not be a global variable; use `for (var lt ...` to keep it seperate for each recursion level.

Comment: So in fixing that, each time it iterates it just appends the next letter to the set, so the last iteration ends up with 7 a's followed by 7 groups of b-f within the same set. How do you make it so it will iterate over each individual a (and then so on)? I put a for loop to encompass the creation of the copy variables(using setCopy[j] = letters[it]; rather than .push) which replaces each letter how I want, but will not check each index (i,e, eeeeeee -> feeeeee -> ffeeee). How do you check each index individually then?

Comment: @Orcinuss I added a code example; as you'll see, it's a straightforward implementation of the steps I listed.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you for working through this with me.

Comment: @Orcinuss A recursive function with a loop inside it is a common pattern for this kind of problem. It's worth getting a good understanding of how iteration and recursion can work together to create combinations, permutations, Cartesian products, ...